# Building a maven project for deployment

Tags: java, maven, m2e

Hello all I'm pretty new to using maven to build Java project so I'm sure the solution to my problem will be quite easy. I have installed the Eclipse Maven plugin and created a maven project. I now wish to package this project and distribute it as a runnable jar file. However when I run

```
mvn package
```

and then try to run the jar file I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/Formatter
```

The pom for this particular file looks like so:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>pcap.csv.xml</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the main class in the jar plugin:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>main.Formatter</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

If you want to distribute a single jar you need to use a single-jarifier (fatjar, jarjar, onejar, etc.)

Comment: However once I do that and run mvn assembly:single I get the following error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pcap/csv/xml-0/0/1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies/jar`

Comment: @ChrisManess When trying to run it, or package it? What specifically are you typing?

Comment: `java [jar-name.jar]` I've also tried `java [jar-name.jar] main.Formatter` to no avail.

Comment: @ChrisManess That's not how you run a jar file; `java -jar [jarFile]`